# Save the shape of a rectangular selection in an Emacs register

Tags: emacs

I need to repeatedly copy text from a fixed size rectangular region and I'd like to be able to save the shape of that rectangular region in a register so I don't have to keep re-creating the same size.

1. `cua-set-rectangle-mark` (`<C-return>`)
2. Move point to create a region 8x16 (*note: this is the step I want to remove*)
3. `piture-clear-rectangle` (`C-c C-k`)
4. Move point to new location.
5. `picture-yank-rectangle` (`C-c C-y`)

I'd like to replace steps 1 and 2 with a single 'paste rectangular region from register' command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply use a keyboard macro for this?

E.g.:-

```
C-x C-(   [start recording kbd macro]
steps 1-2
C-x C-)   [end recording kbd macro]
```

Then

```
C-x e     [execute kbd macro]
```

Comment: D'oh! I use them every day and still I forgot about macros :-D While this definitely solves my problem it doesn't technically answer the question; I'll accept this as the correct answer if I don't get an answer to "save rectangular region in a register". Cheers, Ben.

Comment: cool, I didn't know off-hand how to save a rectangle to a register, but thought this might sort the problem anyway :) @phils has found a means of doing what you actually want, however, it seems so you ought to accept his answer :)

Comment: His response doesn't answer the question. Creating a macro and giving it a name is the best way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, it doesn't save the *shape*. Keyboard macros ftw, they are sooo useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `copy-rectangle-to-register` and `insert-register`:

> C-x r r runs the command copy-rectangle-to-register, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `register.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x r r.
>
> (copy-rectangle-to-register REGISTER START END &optional DELETE-FLAG)
>
> Copy rectangular region into register REGISTER.
>   With prefix arg, delete as well.
>   To insert this register in the buffer, use C-x r g.
>
> Called from a program, takes four args: REGISTER, START, END and DELETE-FLAG.
>   START and END are buffer positions giving two corners of rectangle.

insert-register:

> C-x r g runs the command insert-register, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `register.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x r g, C-x r i.
>
> (insert-register REGISTER &optional ARG)
>
> Insert contents of register REGISTER.  (REGISTER is a character.)
>   Normally puts point before and mark after the inserted text.
>   If optional second arg is non-nil, puts mark before and point after.
>   Interactively, second arg is non-nil if prefix arg is supplied.

See also:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>: `clear-rectangle`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>: `delete-rectangle`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>: `kill-rectangle`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>: `open-rectangle`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>: `copy-rectangle-to-register`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>: `string-rectangle`
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>: `yank-rectangle`

EDIT:

Right, I completely misunderstood the question.

If you still particularly want to use registers, you could save and re-execute point movements with something like this:

```
(set-register ?a [right right right down down])
(command-execute (get-register ?a))
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem. This copies the text in the rectangular region in to a register, it doesn't save the rectangular _shape_ in a register.